# how do i make a verifier for my html form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, post

```
<div class="entry-container row">
        <div class="signup containerss col">
            <h1 class="center">New Here,</h1>
            <h3 class="center">Signup Here</h3>         
            <form action="signup" class="form-inside" method='post'>
                username<input type='text' name='Username' required/><br>
                password<input type="text" name='Password' required/><br>
                Firstname<input type="text" name='Fname' required/><br>
                Lastname<input type="text" name='Lname' required/><br>
                Date Of Birth<br><input type="date" name='DOB' required/><br>
                Email<input type="text" name='Email' required/><br>
                <input type='submit' name='Submit'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="login float-right col" style="height: 300px;">
            <h1 class="center">Already a Member</h1>
            <h3 class="center">Login Here</h3>
            <form action="login" class="form-inside" method='POST'>
                username<input type='text' name='User' required/><br>
                password<input type='text' name='Pass' required/>
                <input type="submit" name='submit'>

            </form>

        </div>
    <div>
```

here is a simple form for login or signup,
now what I want to do is i want to make a js code that verifies if the username is a string(has no special chars), password is strong enough, email is valid etc, and if everything is perfect ,only then the user must be allowed to submit the form,
if not then I want to tell the mistakes yo the user, while the user is typing
how can I achieve this.
**2 question i want answer to ,**
**1**
I had tried this,

```
<div class='hide' onclick='showerror()' id='error'>error</div>
<style>.hide{display:none;}</style>
<script>function showerror(){
var error= document.getelementbyid('error') 
error.Classlist.toggle('hide')
}</script>
```

how can i call this same function when the user is typing ,
**2**
how can i use regex in js to verify if the textontext of a element is string or not.

Comment: @ajsoler can you please check again ive updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript event for validating form.

```
function ValidateForm()
{
  var inputText1 =  document.form1.text1;
  var inputText2 =  document.form1.text2;
  var inputText3 =  document.form1.text3;  

 //add other elements validation here 

 var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
   if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
  {
 document.form1.text1.focus();
 return true;
}
else
 {
 alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
  document.form1.text1.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript form validation - checking email</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='form-style.css' type='text/css' />
  </head>
  <body onload='document.form1.text1.focus()'>
  <div class="mail">
     <h2>Input an email and Submit</h2>
     <form name="form1" action="#">
        <ul>
           <li><input type='text' name='text1'/></li>
            <li><input type='password' name='text2'/></li>
            <li><input type='text' name='text3'/></li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ValidateForm()"/></li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
     </form>
  </div>
  <script src="email-validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks so much ,can you please explain how can I do the same while the user is typing

Comment: Instead use "onfocusout". Find diffrent events that are available in JS here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_events.htm